# Iterating dictionary in the order I added items, python

Tags: python, dictionary, iteration

Say I create a dictionary like so:

```
self.defaultValues = {}
self.defaultValues["A"] = "10"
self.defaultValues["B"] = "100"
self.defaultValues["C"] = "20"
self.defaultValues["D"] = "12.5"
```

I want to be able to iterate the items in the same order I added them, meaning

```
for k in self.defaultValues:
     print k
```

would result in

```
A
B
C
D
```

Also, if I have another list, not necessarily of the same length. I want to iterate both the dictionary and the list, and if a value exist in the list I will print it, otherwise I will print if form the dictionary. Its easy to do with a simple

```
if self.list.count(value) != 0:
```

But I think there might be a more elegant way to do it.

Thanks!

Comment: second problem: `if value in self.list`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the first problem, use an `OrderedDict`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
d = OrderedDict()
d["A"] = "10"
d["B"] = "100"
d["C"] = "20"
d["D"] = "12.5"
for k in d:
    print k
```

`OrderedDict` respects the order in which elements were inserted.

For your second question (you should really make separate questions for separate problems), you can use `in` to test if an object is in the list:

```
l = [1,2,3,4]
print 1 in l # prints True
print 5 in l # prints False
```

Comment: @Yotam Beware that the `x in mylist` check is not very efficient, so if you're doing a lot of these checks, and especially if the list isn't very short, consider turning `mylist` into a set (`myset = set(mylist)`) and use *that* to check for membership instead (`x in myset`).

Answer (score 4):

For the first part of your question, use [collections.OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

For the second, assuming you still care about the order, you can try (and assuming d is the original dict):

```
tmp_dict = OrderedDict((x, x) for x in l)
tmp_dict.update(d)
```

You now have, in `tmp_dict`, the values you care (`tmp_dict.values()` will display them).